# Error en Package.lok.jso

Tags: json

Les comento que inicie un curso de Desarrollo web. El tema es cuando practicaba hacer branch, hice lio y mezcle dos.Y al descargar Node.js, hice un conflicto el cual me ayudaron a reparar. Pero desde ahi no me responde bien cuando quiero hacer responsive usando mediaqueries.
Si alguien me puede ayudar o decirme donde puedo buscar. Lo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] super agradeceria.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal parece que hay restos del proceso de `merge` en tu archivo `package.lock.json`. Mi sugerencia es que elimines el mismo y ejecutes `npm install` nuevamente. Esto volverá a crear el archivo `package.lock.json`.  Saludos